# How do make a manually arrangeable listview in WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, drag-and-drop

In my application's main window I'd like to have an interface very similar to that of Windows Desktop. There would be a bunch of icons with texts and you can drag them around and position them as you like. The standard ListView would almost do, except that it doesn't support this custom re-arranging. Any ideas on how to achieve this effect short of writing a completely new usercontrol from scratch?

Comment: If saying rearranging you mean ordering, may be you just can order items in list in specified order?

Comment: @Tigran - No, I mean like half of the icons get dragged to the left side of the screen, and the other half - to the right side. Not really ordering - more like placement.

Comment: don't think you have some ither way then make some ownerdraw control. Standart control *does not* support behaviour like that. If we would talking about WPF, the story *at that point* would be completely different.

Comment: @Tigran - I'm VERY unfamiliar with WPF. I've tried doing something in it a couple of times, only to find myself completely lost. The lack of good tutorials also doesn't help (at least I didn't find any). Are you saying that WPF has this functionality out-of-the-box?

Comment: ohhh, yes. :) It's a completely different story. If you're going to create a new application for run on Windows OS (mono does not support it), it's definitely woth to spend a time to study it (if you have a time). For tutorial can have a look on [Wpf Tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/)

Comment: @Tigran - I've tried it, but it only covers the very basics, and pretty sparsely at that. But it doesn't say anything about common patterns and scenarios, best practices, commonly used properties, etc. Every WPF control has half-a-zillion properties and they can be extended in infinitely many ways, and... Well, I'm lost. :P

Comment: Well, if this project you're asking for is personal, I would suggest just starting it in WPF and discover it during development, if basics more or less you already know. During the development you will find out the benefits of it (very big, especially in code design terms). Don't look on all together, it's impossible to understand everything immideately, focus on what you need for your project and the rest will come time after time.

Comment: @Tigran - well, OK, I'll give it another shot. But I honestly have no idea where to start... Would you be OK with providing me with a bit of assistance in the chat? I just need to get started.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10264/discussion-between-tigran-and-vilx)

Answer (score 0):

For this to be done you have to add max no of items into the list view. As I know list view will allow us to drag items only into already occupied area. You can fill the extra space using `listview.Items.Add("")`

Once u have to add some new item  u can replace the first blank item with the new item. I tried this thing and it's working. One thing u have to handle is sorting. While sorting u have to omit the blank items.